# Windows Filtering Platform user mode or kernel mode?

Tags: filter, wfp

I am using the Windows Filtering Platform. I want to create a traffic filter, security manager, which monitors packets and network events or blocks urls... I know most of the WFP functions can be called from either user mode or kernel mode. I am wondering whether to write my filter by using kernel-mode functions or user-mode ones?? Is there any kind of network actions that can only be captured by using kernel-mode driver? Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance for any help on the matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alexandre is correct, some things can only be done with kernel mode WFP callout drivers.

However, you might also want to look at my project [WinDivert](http://reqrypt.org/windivert.html) (LGPL) which lifts some WFP kernel-mode functionality (i.e. intercepting and modifying packets) into a user-mode API.  WinDivert provides the callout driver for you.

Comment: hey @basil I tried WinDivert, I want to thank you for the great job you've done but I'm afraid it doesn't support HTTPS ! the webfilter demo app can't block URLs starting with https.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23151135/windows-filtering-platform-to-filter-https-from-managed-code

Answer (score 6):

WFP Callouts can only be deployed using kernel mode drivers. As far as I know modifying packets (NAT, port forwarding, etc) can only be done using callouts on kernel mode drivers.

UPDATE:

- User-mode application may be used to do shallow packet inspecting and some simple stream operations as well as control kernel mode drivers.
- Kernel mode drivers may do deep and shallow packet inspection and all kinds of stream manipulation, but cannot interact with common applications without the use of user mode applications implementing the WFP API.

Comment: I have read the introduction of WFP and [Converting Components to Use WFP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463267.aspx#EVD) I understand that User-mode application or service can  perform advanced TCP connection management-such as proxying, duplicating, or cloning connections. So, what is the difference between usermode and kernel mode?

Comment: The User-mode application may interact and control kernel mode drivers, but there are situations such as deep packet inspection and modification that only can be done through kernel mode drivers implementing WFP callouts.